# Update a column in a table repeatedly

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp(ColSelect NVARCHAR(400),ColParValues XML)
```

that **ColSelect** contains SQL Select Statement and **ColParValues** contains some xml data for parameter value in ColSelect
for example ColSelectcontains:

```
 "SELECT [$12]+19/[$16]-[$54]"
```

and col 2 contains name value pair that refer to ColSelect parameters

How can I update my table that replace each parameter with relevant value from ColParValues. I use this statement:

```
update #tmp
SET
ColSelect=REPLACE(ColSelect,c.value('@Value','nvarchar(10)'),c.value('@Res','DECIMAL(24,12)'))
FROM #tmp t1
    CROSS APPLY t1.ColParValues.nodes('/root/r') AS n(c)
```

but this statement replace just one parameter value in each row.
And this is sample data [link](http://www.testalims.com/Capture.jpg)

Comment: it's good if you could give some sample data.

Comment: sample data [link](http://testalims.com/Capture.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one solution :

```
create table #tmp (colselect varchar(200),colparvalues xml)

insert into #tmp (colselect,colparvalues)
values ('select case when [$71]+[$29]+10<25 then 1 else 0 end'
        ,'<root><r Value="[$71]" Res="1"/><r Value="[$29]" Res="5"/></root>'),
('select case when [$95]*[$29]+10<25 then 1 else 0 end'
        ,'<root><r Value="[$95]" Res="3"/><r Value="[$29]" Res="5"/></root>')

WHILE @@ROWCOUNT >0 
update #tmp
SET
ColSelect=REPLACE(ColSelect,c.value('@Value','nvarchar(10)'),c.value('@Res','DECIMAL(24,12)'))
FROM #tmp t1
    CROSS APPLY t1.ColParValues.nodes('/root/r') AS n(c)
WHERE t1.colselect LIKE'%'+replace(c.value('@Value','nvarchar(10)'),'[','')+'%'


select * from #tmp

drop table #tmp
```

However, very much similar to cursor in performance. Check the performance. Use if ok.

Comment: Thank for response. I cant understand, why `code` LIKE'%'+replace(c.value('@Value','nvarchar(10)'),'[','')+'%'

Comment: @user2377017 : If not used it will consider as pattern matching set by SQL with element `$` and other integers.  Eg. : `select 1 where 'a'  like '[a..z]'`

Comment: Ddo you trust to your answer, this is best way?

Comment: @user2377017 : I cannot see any other way. May be someone can. Check the performance and decide.

Comment: I solve this challenge with SQL CLR function and Regex. But main idea is yours. thank you